# Python OSError Initializing from file failed when trying to load a simple CSV file

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and have installed Anaconda. I launched the Jupyter notebook and was trying to load a CSV file from the local folder in my Download directory.

What I get what this long error message:
[image]
[image]

I have tried looking up the error message online, uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda in my machine, but the same error message keeps popping up. I know this may sound stupid since loading the file should be something that is a breeze, but I have spent hours trying to find the solution with no avail.

Anybody knows how to solve this problem, or at least tell me where I did wrong? I use Python 3 for this. Thank you so much!

Comment: u r loading a folder not a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read it with inbuild csv

```
import csv
x=csv.reader('filename')
```

Comment: Can you explain more? The file name is who-suicide-statistics that I take from Kaggle dataset.

Comment: it must end with .csv . are you able to open that file in excel ?, i m not able to open kaggle now

Comment: Oh i see! Thanks a lot for the enlightenment Prashant!! That works!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the location of your file , hope it works . Because I think there is problem in the path.